# How can I repeat a loop for random walk?

Tags: python

I want to calculate average for random walk for 1000 times to get good average. My code for this random walk is

```
import math
import random
from matplotlib import pyplot
position = 0
walk = [position]
steps = 10
for i in xrange(steps):
    step = 1 if random.randint(0, 1) else -1
    position += step
    walk. Append(position)
    
    print((walk))

pyplot.hist(walk)
pyplot.show()
```

So, what is the best way to make python repeat it many times and calculate the average for these random walks?

Comment: You already mastered one loop; why not add another loop around this code?

Comment: In other words, put a `for` loop around your `for` loop!

Comment: if i putted new for it will just repeat it i want to repeat it and find the final average

Comment: @Diesha so what's the problem, you don't know how to calculate average? That's stuff from ground school iirc

Comment: hhh please run the code first it gives me histogram, my question is i need histogram for the average for as example  1000 repeated times ?

Comment: Could you post 5 examples somewhere that do not work? Then I may get what you want to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be easier to do if you break it down into smaller functions, for example making the main part of your code a function

```
def makewalk(steps):
  position = 0
  walk = [position]
  for i in xrange(steps):
    step = 1 if random.randint(0, 1) else -1
    position += step
    walk.append(position)
  return walk # instead of simply printing it
```

Also, you could use inbuilt functions to reduce it to a few lines

```
import numpy
def makewalk(N):
  steps = numpy.random.randint(0, 2, N) * 2 - 1
  # an array of length N with random integers between 0 (inclusive) and 2 (exclusive)
  # multiplying it by two and subtracting 1 the numbers 0 and 1 become -1 and 1 respectively
  walk = numpy.cumsum(steps) # what it says, a cumulative sum
  return walk
```

Now just loop over it 1000 times

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
steps = 10000
numwalks = 1000
walks = [makewalk(steps) for i in xrange(numwalks)]
```

There are your walks, do whatever you like with them, and since the walks are numpy arrays you can easily compute the elementwise sum without loops

```
averagewalk = numpy.sum(walks, 0)*1.0/numwalks # sums along the 0th axis and returns an array of length steps
```